# Second order ODE with varying parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have this ODE: 
$$\epsilon {f}^{\prime\prime} +f^\prime=2x+1 \\f(0)=1\\f(1)=4\\ \epsilon\ll1$$
I want to find the exact solution which is given by :
$$f(x)=x^2+x+2-e^{\frac{-1}{\epsilon}x}+\epsilon\Big(2(1-x)-2e^{\frac{-1}{\epsilon}x}\Big) $$

My attempt:
Rewriting the equation:
$${f}^{\prime\prime} +\frac{1}{\epsilon} f^\prime=\frac{2}{\epsilon}x+\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

Homogeneous solution:$$f_H=c_1+c_2 e^{\frac{-1}{\epsilon}x}$$
It seems that the take the particular solution as:
$$f_p=Ax^2 +Bx +C\\{f_P}^\prime= 2Ax+B\\ {f_P}^{\prime\prime}=2A$$ 
substitute in the problem:$$2A+\frac{1}{\epsilon}(2Ax+B)=\frac{2}{\epsilon}x+\frac{1}{\epsilon} \Longrightarrow A=1, B=1-2\epsilon$$

-General solution:
$$f=c_1+c_2 e^{\frac{-1}{\epsilon}x}+x^2+(1-2\epsilon)x$$
-Applying boundary conditions we get:
$$c_1=\frac{2(1+\epsilon)-e^\frac{-1}{\epsilon}}{1-e^\frac{-1}{\epsilon}},\qquad c_2=\frac{-(1+2\epsilon)}{ 1-e^\frac{-1}{\epsilon}}$$
-By neglecting the term $e^\frac{-1}{\epsilon}$ (which I am not sure why!! ) we get the given solution.

My questions here:

-what about the constant C in the particular solution?

-why we didn’t use a linear polynomial as a particular solution because the right hand side is a linear polynomial ?

Comment: Is your original DE $\epsilon f''+f'=2x+1$ or $\epsilon f''+f=2x+1?$

Comment: yes, it is the first one , sorry for forgetting the prime sign in the rewrites equation. I will edit it

Comment: So the $C$ in the particular solution ansatz is superfluous, because you already know it's going to be annihilated by the operator $\epsilon d^2/dx^2+d/dx.$ If it's in the homogeneous solution, there's no point in including it in a particular solution ansatz.

Comment: Are you sure the solution you cited is labeled "exact solution" or is it the $O(ϵ)$ approximation of the boundary layer approximation, composed of "inner" and "outer" solutions?

Comment: @LutzL It was actually written f as exact solution when solving the outer problem of the boundary layer.The outer approximate solution doesn’t include the exponential terms

Comment: As the boundary layer is at $x=0$, the outer equation is $f'(x)=2x+1$, $f(1)=4$ with solution $f(x)=x^2+x+2$, without the other terms from the inner solution and first order correction.

Comment: The outer solution as in my notes with taking terms for order 1 and order $\epsilon$ is $f^{out}= x^2 +x+2+\epsilon 2(1-x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C$ gets combined with $c_1$ of the homogeneous solution. Or one could just say that the trial function is $x(Ax+B)$.

For the same reason, as the exponential factor $0$ is a characteristic root of the left side, the linear trial solution $Ax+B$ gets multiplied with $x$.

If you were to first integrate both sides, you would find that
$$
ϵf'+f=x^2+x+c_1
$$
where you directly see that the particular solution needs to be a quadratic polynomial.